# Draw responsive particles on canvas by javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, responsive, onresize

I want to change these code so that it would be responsive and changing the browser size won't be an issue

**first code: i need change this to responsive**

```js
var canvasDots = function() {
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      colorDot = '#00bdbf',
      color = '#00bdbf';
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.style.display = 'block';
  ctx.fillStyle = colorDot;
  ctx.lineWidth = .1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;

  var mousePosition = {
    x: 30 * canvas.width / 100,
    y: 30 * canvas.height / 100
  };

  var dots = {
    nb: 350,
    distance: 60,
    d_radius: 100,
    array: []
  };

  function Dot(){
    this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;

    this.vx = -.5 + Math.random();
    this.vy = -.5 + Math.random();

    this.radius = Math.random();
  }

  Dot.prototype = {
    create: function(){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      ctx.fill();
    },

    animate: function(){
      for(i = 0; i < dots.nb; i++){

        var dot = dots.array[i];

        if(dot.y < 0 || dot.y > canvas.height){
          dot.vx = dot.vx;
          dot.vy = - dot.vy;
        }
        else if(dot.x < 0 || dot.x > canvas.width){
          dot.vx = - dot.vx;
          dot.vy = dot.vy;
        }
        dot.x += dot.vx;
        dot.y += dot.vy;
      }
    },

    line: function(){
      for(i = 0; i < dots.nb; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < dots.nb; j++){
          i_dot = dots.array[i];
          j_dot = dots.array[j];

          if((i_dot.x - j_dot.x) < dots.distance && (i_dot.y - j_dot.y) < dots.distance && (i_dot.x - j_dot.x) > - dots.distance && (i_dot.y - j_dot.y) > - dots.distance){
            if((i_dot.x - mousePosition.x) < dots.d_radius && (i_dot.y - mousePosition.y) < dots.d_radius && (i_dot.x - mousePosition.x) > - dots.d_radius && (i_dot.y - mousePosition.y) > - dots.d_radius){
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(i_dot.x, i_dot.y);
              ctx.lineTo(j_dot.x, j_dot.y);
              ctx.stroke();
              ctx.closePath();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  function createDots(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(i = 0; i < dots.nb; i++){
      dots.array.push(new Dot());
      dot = dots.array[i];

      dot.create();
    }

    dot.line();
    dot.animate();
  }

  window.onmousemove = function(parameter) {
    mousePosition.x = parameter.pageX;
    mousePosition.y = parameter.pageY;
  }

  mousePosition.x = window.innerWidth / 2;
  mousePosition.y = window.innerHeight / 2;

  setInterval(createDots, 1000/30); 
};

window.onload = function() {
  canvasDots();
};
```

```css
html, body {
  background: #333;
}
canvas{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

**seconde code: i need change this to responsive**

```js
var livePatern = {
  canvas: null,
  context: null,
  cols: 0,
  rows: 0,
  colors: [252, 251, 249, 248, 241, 240],
  triangleColors: [],
  destColors: [],
  
  init: function(){
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.cols = Math.floor(document.body.clientWidth / 24);
    this.rows = Math.floor(document.body.clientHeight / 24) + 1;
    
    this.canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    this.canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    
    this.drawBackground();
    this.animate();
  },
  
  drawTriangle: function(x, y, color, inverted){
    inverted = inverted == undefined ? false : inverted;

    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.moveTo(x, y);
    this.context.lineTo(inverted ? x - 22 : x + 22, y + 11);
    this.context.lineTo(x, y + 22);
    this.context.fillStyle = "rgb("+color+","+color+","+color+")";
    this.context.fill();
    this.context.closePath();
  },
  
  getColor: function(){    
    return this.colors[(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6))];
  },
  
  drawBackground: function(){
    var eq = null;
    var x = this.cols;
    var destY = 0;
    var color, y;
    
    while(x--){
      eq = x % 2;
      y = this.rows;

      while(y--){
        destY = Math.round((y-0.5) * 24);

        this.drawTriangle(x * 24 + 2, eq == 1 ? destY : y * 24, this.getColor());
        this.drawTriangle(x * 24, eq == 1 ? destY  : y * 24, this.getColor(), true);
      }
    }
  },
  
  animate: function(){
    var me = this;

    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.cols);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.rows);
    var eq = x % 2;

    if (eq == 1) {
      me.drawTriangle(x * 24, Math.round((y-0.5) * 24) , this.getColor(), true);
    } else {
      me.drawTriangle(x * 24 + 2, y * 24, this.getColor());
    }

    setTimeout(function(){    
      me.animate.call(me);
    }, 10);
  },
};

!function(){livePatern.init();}()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

canvas{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I want to use:

```
window.onresize = function() {

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

  //call again function;
}
```

but animations were duplicated.

Comment: Do you want the canvas resolution to match the window with the content scaled to fit, or scale the mouse coordinates to match the scaled canvas content, or increase the resolution and add more content to fill the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the size of the canvas on load and save that for all the upcoming rendering. But instead you could do something like;

```
//pseudo code, including only the idea.
windown.onload = function () {

  var canvas = document.querySelector(...),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  Dots.init();

  function prepareCanvas (w, h) {
    //set width and height
    //do more nessessary stuff
  }

  (function loop () {
    var w = window.innerWidth,
        h = window.innerHeight;

     prepareCanvas(w, h);
     Dots.render(context, w, h);


    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  })();
}
```

So basically, add the width and height as parameters to the render method, so display size wont matter if it changes.

**UPDATE, due to the comments**

Cache the dimensions, than that wont happen more often than you need it.

```
window.onload = function () {
  var w, h, resized = true;

  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    resized = true;
  });

  (function loop() {
    if (resized) {
      //get w, h
      prepareCanvas(w, h);
      resized = false;
    }

     Dots.render(context, w, h);
  })();

}
```